# ubuntu server time

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have a ubuntu server on aws, and when I do `new Date().getTime()` on the server the time seems a bit off (a couple of minutes).

How do I get it to be more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

See the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime) for more information.

Comment: Do i need to do anything after installation.

Comment: Nope that's it. You can manually set the time servers if you are into that sort of thing, but it isn't necessary.